# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment

Tags: ubuntu

I can use gedit open file  in terminal,but when I close the terminal ,I  gedit the file ,then show :error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

```
(gedit:10183): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
hadoop@hadoop1:~$
```

Comment: Off topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

When you run software as another user you're in fact starting the new minimal and isolated environment that doesn't carry on some "excessive" variables (among others variables responsible for injecting libraries or setting certain privileges). Replace your sudo nautilus call with the following - it will carry on user-specific x server settings from the current session:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY nautilus
```

for root

```
sudo pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY nautilus
```

Taken from here : https://askubuntu.com/a/467994/185132

Comment: The mentioned question on ask ubuntu discussed about `nautilus`, so it used it in the command. Making that pattern in use for answering this question, you should replace `nautilus` with `gedit`.

Answer (score 2):

Same like m3asmi said but with gedit and not nautilus:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit
```

for root

```
sudo pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit
```

Comment: Accept at least an answer here first if you are quoting from there: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27424115/2636873